# how to replace @ string and capitalize letters with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a line needs to replace as;

```
arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user@xxx.com",)
```

to

```
arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user XXX)
```

that i just need to change second part of '@' string

THX yael

Comment: Why does `user@domain.com` remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo 'arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user@xxx.com",)' | sed 's/@\([^.@]*\)\.[^"@]*\([^@]*\)$/ \U\1\2/g'
arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user XXX",)
```

**OR**

```
$ echo 'arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user@xxx.com",)' | sed 's/^\([^@]*@[^@]*\)@\([^.@]*\)\.[^"@]*\([^@]*\)$/\1 \U\2\3/g'
arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user XXX",)
```

**Update:**

```
$ echo 'arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user@xxx.com",)' | sed 's/^\([^@]*@[^@]*\)@\([^.@]*\)\.[^"]*.*$/\1 \U\2)/g'
arguments = ("-e", "-d", "user@domain.com", "-m", "user XXX)
```

Comment: The **Update:** drops the final `",` from the string. (never mind -- the question changed :()

Comment: Yes, I saw that after my comment -- I hate it when that happens :)